# How to pass results of results to another command in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, command, kill

Using the following combination of `grep`, `ls` and `awk` I get a list of **pid** that I need to kill:

```
grep -hP '^\d+$' `ls -lad /dir/*/pid | grep -P '/dir/\d+/pid' | awk '{ print $9 }'`

13234
18972
24322
```

How can I now add `kill -9` command to this command combination to kill those processes?

I already using `` ` `` characters to pass `awk` results to `grep` command, so I assume I cannot use it again to pass it to `kill`, correct?